# Image Update via CSV import

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, image, csv, importexport

I am running Magento 1.8.1.0 Community and have over 700 simple products that need images assigned to them. These images are already assigned and uploaded to the configurable products.

I have done a catalog export and made a new sheet with only one product (config & simple) on it, copied image paths into the proper places, but when I do the import nothing has changed.

[Google Docs - Click this to see what I am working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1kRsTp1Wi_bAC8wyq1CvH00APWESJDaepcuzZsi5XU/edit?usp=sharing)

I've seen articles about this being possible but can't seem to get it working for myself. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `SKU` column in your CSV.

Comment: I missed the column in my copy/paste action. It is there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import products with images magento is looking in the /media/import/ directory for the image. If it is not found there the image is ignored.

As a quick fix you can try duplicating you media/catalog/product/ list of dirs in /media/import/ (spare cache and placeholder if they exist).

This will force the product images to be imported, but keep in mind that it will create duplicates of the original images.

Comment: Okay, I saw a few articles about having images in the import folder but it wasn't working before. For the image path in the CSV, does it have to start with a "/" or it just be the character? -- Example: [A]"/1/4/14-1000_surfer_girl_peach_1.jpg" -- or -- [B]"1/4/14-1000_surfer_girl_peach_1.jpg"

Comment: [A] is the correct one /1/4/14blala.jpg

Actually you must always begin with / even if you don't have subdirectories. 

For example a file /media/import/image.jpg is referenced as /image.jpg in the csv

Comment: Okay great, I'll try this and get back to you. Is there any other reason that an import/update from CSV would not assign images to a product?

Comment: I guess there should be plenty, such as dir permissions, faulty csv, image file names with spaces, etc and as always the Universe messing with you.But you have to address them individually.